# PHP convert MySQL string field to numeric array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem in a PHP file with an array from a field from a MySQL table:

```
<?php 
            require "lib/config.php";
            $users = array();
            error_reporting(0);

            $UTB = $config['dbTableNames']['users'];
            mysql_connect($config['dbConnection']['host'], $config['dbConnection']['user'], $config['dbConnection']['pass']);
                mysql_select_db($config['dbConnection']['name']);
                $GuID = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Channels FROM $UTB");

                if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
                    while ($rGuID = mysql_fetch_array($GuID)) {        
                        $uID = $rGuID['ID'];     
                        $users[$uID]['channels'] = array($rGuID['Channels']);
                        printf($rGuID['Channels'] . ' ');
                    }
                }
```

Result after printf (used just for display the values) is:

```
0,1 0,1 0 0,1 0,1 0,1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If I set this array manually (after while loop)  my AjaxChat site is working OK, but I have at least 40 users to configure like this:

```
    $users[1]['channels'] = array(0, 1);
    $users[2]['channels'] = array(0, 1);
    $users[3]['channels'] = array(0);
...
```

`Channels` field type (in MySQL table) is VARCHAR size 255 with values `0` or `0,1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for the size of ***$rGuID['channels']*** string and based on that can directly assign array(0) or array(0,1) to users array in the loop